# Cómo dar formato a una tabla en React teniendo un JSON como fuente de datos?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo React y tengo una aplicación en la cual tengo un JSON que quiero que sea mostrado como una tabla en React, tengo este código

```
import Data from '../components/users.json';

export default withAuth(class Users extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end', marginTop: '150px', marginRight: '500px', color: 'black' }}>
                {Data.map((user, index) => {
                    return <div>
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{user.id}</td>
                                <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Pero en lugar de mostrar el encabezado una vez lo hace dos veces y no en forma de lista, como se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es básicamente por la forma en como renderiza su componente, cuando itera un `array` o una colección, en este caso con `map`, todo lo que esté dentro se "repetirá" de acuerdo a la cantidad de elementos, si tiene 2 elementos mostrará dos veces una tabla.

Además para añadir clases, se utiliza `className=""` en lugar de `class`.

La solución añadir dentro del `map` solo las filas `tr` del contenido de la tabla, para que se muestre como una tabla común y añadir los elementos `thead` y `tbody` para evitar los warnings.

Además se recomienda utilizar [llaves *(keys)*](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) cuando se itera elementos, valor único como el id.

```
return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        marginTop: "150px",
        marginRight: "500px",
        color: "black"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Data.map((user, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={user.id}>
                  <td>{user.id}</td>
                  <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                  <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/xp58z8jylp)</kbd>

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu explicacion, ese era mi error. Ahora ya entiendo como funciona. Ten un buen día :D

Comment: Lo que mencionas de la llave, me podria servir por ejemplo si quiero darle clic al ID de cualquiera y me visualice mas detalles del mismo en otra Ventana?

Comment: @AlbertoArambula no, esto ayuda a react para saber si algún elemento cambio o se agregaron nuevos, usted para ver en otra ventana manejaría [eventos](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)