# como puedo recuperar valores de un objeto en javascript

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

Tengo un array de esta manera

```
array=[
    {'fechacarga':'29-01-2019','id_articulo':'1','nombre':'paleta','cantidad':'40','mensaje':'sin cargar'},
    {'fechacarga':'29-01-2019','id_articulo':'2','nombre':'bombon','cantidad':'10','mensaje':'sin cargar'}
    ]
```

pero tengo problemas para sacar los valores, lo intente como objeto y como array pero no termino de comprender los tutoriales, existe alguna manera sencilla de hacerlo?

obtengo el valor desde una api para procesarlo en react native

```
  this.props.info.map(nombre => (
  <Text
    key={nombre}
    style={styles.price_Info}>
    {nombre}
  </Text>
))
```

Comment: [En esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242869/c%C3%B3mo-dar-formato-a-una-tabla-en-react-teniendo-un-json-como-fuente-de-datos/242878#242878) hay algo relacionado con su pregunta quizá podría ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu estas mapeando el array, entonces vas a ir objeto del array por objeto.
los dos parametros que le pasaras `(objeto,i)`, uno es el valor del array, en este caso sera un objeto y el `i` es el indice del objeto.

con objeto vas a acceder a las propiedades el objeto
por ejemplo el nombre, seria `objeto.nombre` y asi lo haras con los otros valores del array.

```
  this.props.info.map((objeto,i) => (
  <Text
    key={i}
    style={styles.price_Info}>
    {objeto.nombre}
  </Text>
))
```

espero explicarme